# Phaser 3 Text Inverted Crop Box

Tags: canvas, phaser-framework

I'm trying to create a `Text` object in Phaser 3 that you can scroll up and down interactively, and I'm having trouble finding some functionality that will support this. I understand that I can crop the top of the text with `Text.setCrop(...)` but that will only suffice to crop either the top or the bottom of the text object, not both. What I need is the ability to either set multiple crop boxes on the Text object, or a sort of "inverted" crop box which will allow me to render only what's inside the box and hide the rest of it.

Anyone aware of a trick or something that will allow me to do this? I can't use `BitmapText` or a `Sprite` object for this, it has to be a `Text` object﻿.

Comment: Without code I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. It almost sounds like you just need to add a rectangle above/below the text box and then have functionality to move the text under it?

Comment: @JamesSkemp sorry for the missing context, I figured out the answer and added some details below

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I can use a `Phaser.Display.Masks.GeometryMask` to acheive the desired effect. Unfortunately Phaser 3 does not support masks on container children, but as long as the `Text` object is not a direct child of the container, the mask will hide the overflow content on both the top and bottom of the Text:

```js
/**
 * Unfortunately because of the container child masking issue in Phaser 3,
 * we cannot add the content directly as a child of the container.
 * Thus if the container mutates, we will need to manually mutate the content (and mask) along with it.
 * For more info refer to: https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/issues/3673
 */
let x = 100
let y = 100
container = scene.add.container(x, y)
container.content = container.scene.add.text(
  container.x - container.width / 2, 
  container.y - container.height / 2,
  "", container.defaultStyles
)
this.content.setOrigin(0, 0)

// set up a mask on the content
// this will hide overflow text when we scroll
let maskShape = scene.add.graphics(container.x, container.y)

maskShape
  .clear()
  .fillStyle(0x000000, 0)
  .fillRect(
    container.x - container.width / 2, 
    container.y - container.height / 2,
    container.width, container.height
  )
let mask = container.createGeometryMask(maskShape)
container.content.setMask(mask)
```